# System.ServiceModel.Discovery Missing?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, f#, service-discovery

I need System.ServiceModel.Discovery, but it seems to be missing from all System.ServiceModel.XXX nuget packages. Do i need to reference an old package, or does the implementation lie elsewhere now?

I need it for WCF Discovery pattern, due to the UdpDiscoveryEndpoint() living inside.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/january/foundations-discover-a-new-wcf-with-discovery

Comment: I presume this is for .NET Core? Only a small subset of WCF is supported there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need add a reference to the System.ServiceModel.Discovery. Select **Project**-> **Add Reference** ,then select the name you need.

Thanks.